Prove that a covering of a set of sequences is infinite for a certain radius
So say I had some set of sequences that were bounded above by 1. If I had a ball of radius 2 centered at any one of these sequences, I would only need one ball to cover the entire set S. But why would I require infinitely many balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ to cover S? Perhaps I am just fundamentally misunderstanding what the definition of ball is, especially one centered at a sequence.
Take the space $\ell^{\infty}$ as the space of all bounded sequences

Is the ball centered at the limit of the converging sequence? Or does the ball cover the entire sequence?

Well this is where there is confusion actually. if the sequence is infinite but there is only a finite radius how can one guarantee that the entire sequence is covered. It is not centered at a limit of a converging sequence though

Consider the set $\{\delta_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\ell^\infty$, where $\delta_n$ is the sequence defined by $\delta_n(n)=1$ and every other $\delta_n(k)$ is $0$. For any distinct $m,n\in\Bbb N$, $\|\delta_m-\delta_n\|_\infty=1$.

Ok so if I am understanding this correctly, you are saying that the distance between terms of a sequence is 1 which is greater than 1/2 but it is infinite so it will require infinite amount of balls of radius 1/2 to cover. But why would it not require infinite amount of balls of radius 2 to cover this also?

You understood correctly, it was because $1>1/2$. The same reasoning doesn't apply to $2$ since $1<2$.
